# Image in layout is not the correct size

Tags: android, eclipse, image, layout

This is how it looks:

[image]

I've added an image to my layout. Because the image was a big small, and ended up in the middle of my screen, not filling the entire width of the screen, i had to stretch it out. With that, the letters obviously stretch out as well, which makes it look bad. I know that this might be unfixable. Every image needs to be stretched out, so the colors are fine, but the letters are always a bit hazy after that.
If this has no solutions at all, just tell me so I know that. If you think you know how to fix this, please help.

Don't think it's relevant, but this is the code that i added the image with:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.MainActivity">


    <ImageView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/rkz_logo4"
          android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
         />
```

Comment: The easiest and maybe only solution is to edit it before in photoshop or with this thing similar to photoshop online : http://www.sumopaint.com/home/

Comment: this is a problem you always will stumple over. You have to provide your images to fit to all screens. look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html. That means, you have to put different images in the layout folders dependant on the screen size/density...

Comment: android:scaleType="center" or android:scaleType="centerInside" or android:scaleType="centerCrop"

Comment: The problem is with pour image resolution and as Image in your screenshot is not very complicated and hard to create, the last and best solution is to create that image with higher resolution in a drawing software,

Comment: I'm trying to create a picture in paint, but I have to creat it and slim it in that much, because i know in the layout it will stretch out. When i slim it in pain, the resolution is already decreasing, so when it stretches out, the size is good, but the resolution is just not good, because i can't keep it in the same shape as i found the image..

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the attributes android: scaleType = "fitXY" and replace the android: layout_width = "fill_parent" on android: layout_width = "wrap_content"

```
<ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/rkz_logo4"
      android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
/>
```

Comment: That slims the image in to a smaller size. Everything is clear, but it's not width enough to fill my screen from left to right, which is what i want.

Comment: You can convert drawable to bitmap, resize bitmap and programmatically set

Answer (score 0):

Create MyImageView.class

```
public class MyImageView extends ImageView {

public final static int WIDTH_IMAGE = 640;
public final static int HEIGHT_IMAGE = 200;
public MyImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = width * HEIGHT_IMAGE / WIDTH_IMAGE;
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
}
```

in xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<your.package.MyImageView    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/image_banner"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/rkz_logo4"
android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Comment: I got the reverse comment on another post, the center crop makes it zoom in completely, the FitXY just stretches it out. Both not the desired outcome, but FitXY gets way closer, as the colors are stretched out right